# I need that textBox would retain its last inputted value

Tags: c#, textbox

I need that textBox would retain its last inputted value after closing/opening its parent form.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Update!**

textBox sample is shown above. 
I need to retain textBox last inputted value (e.g. number 3) after closing/opening parent form. Because it disappears every time after opening/closing parent form.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar >= '1') && (e.KeyChar <= '9')) 
        return;

    if (e.KeyChar == 8) 
        ((TextBox)sender).Clear();

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Then you save that value somewhere. If you re-open a form there will be a new instance of that form (and textbox) so they're not "related"

Comment: And what´s your problem? What did you try? Where are you stuck? We don´t want to ask what you´ve already tried and why that didn´t work for you. Don´t make it difficult to us to help you.

Comment: You can retain that value with the help of some hidden fields and get those whenever required

Comment: that's great advice!  I could guess. ) If I knew how to do that professionaly I wouldn't ask that.

Comment: @Msorich Could you describe the problem a tad bit more? In steps maybe? eg: 1. Open the form with the textbox. 2. enter value in textbox. 3. close form. 4. open form and re-assign value

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working with WPF or WinForms, you can handle the Closing event or override the OnClosing method of the base class to do just that.
Remember to store that value outside of the window object it is currently in, since closing a window means you turn its object into a null-reference. Then the value will still be lost.

Comment: I have no clue how to organize that. Please help with a code.

Comment: Well, subscribing to events or overriding base classes is one of the advanced basics of programming in C#. When I learned creating user interfaces with WPF, [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/getting-started/hello-wpf/) was very helpful in explaining the why with the how. [This section](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/xaml/events-in-xaml/) is about events. Also, the keyPress method in your example is actually an event-handler; it handles the keyPress event of the textBox1 object.